# Rails return model subsets, a = false always, a = true sometimes

Tags: activerecord, set, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Assume there is a model, `Users` and `Users` has the field `admin` (just an example).

The query must always return all `Users` where `admin == false` but only when asked to do so, to also return all `Users` where `admin == true`, but in one single DB request.

so the return subsets might be:

where `A` is `admin == false`

where `B` is `admin == true`

Return `A` OR `A ∪ B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
scope :not_admins, -> { where(admin: false) } // this is A
scope :admins, -> { where(admin: true) } // this is B

def self.example(include_admins = false)
  if include_admins
    self.not_admins.or(self.admins) // A U B
  else
    self.not_admins // A
  end
end
```

then you just call `User.example()` or `User.example(true)` depending on if you want `A` or `A U B`

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.